# how does android store and run programs

Tags: android, jar, zip, apk, dalvik

Android stores it's programs in APK format, which is a modified version of ZIP/JAR.

When these APK files are installed, they are stored in /system/app/$APKNAME.apk.

Some of the apps in this dir also have a $APKNAME.obex file.

These APK files contain some of the fallowing

```
META-INF
    MANIFEST.MF
    CERT.RSA
    CERT.SF
SHA1-Digest
res
AndroidManifest.xml
classes.dex
resources.arsc
```

So what I want to know is what are the .obex files and are androids program decompressed from the APK/ZIP/JAR at runtime and how?

Comment: Sounds like an APK is a whole lot like a JAR.  Which is to say, not even modified ZIP -- just a regular ZIP, but with particular files in particular places within it.

Comment: Keep in mind that obex are more than just decompressed, they are also optimized and verified.  This makes it so that the verifier has to do less work, and you don't have to do as much optimization at runtime (nonobviously you still have to do some).

Comment: @cHao OK, I'm really wanting to know the process from the install of an APK to the launch/run.

Comment: @KristopherMicinski so the .obex files are like Verified keys + Optimized classes.dex ?

Comment: verified _keys_, no, it's not that (I mean, it's not about that kind of verification).  It's verified *bytecode*, to some extent.  Read up on the "bytecode verifier."  Bytecode and verification both require some amount of static analysis, so it makes sense that they sit closely together in the system.  However, you still have to do some stuff at runtime, and also can get better JIT.  Android does trace based JIT, so you can't know which paths will be hottest until runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way that this works is pretty interesting, and gives some key insights into Android's runtime model.  The first thing I'd recommend watching is [Dalvik VM internals](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ptjedOZEXPM), if you plan on doing any serious amount of systems stuff with Android.  (Although, it's obviously old.)  Now, when the Android package manager gets an intent which requires starting a new app it forks off a new virtual machine from an already running *zygote* process.  This is basically a technique which allows the system to get a lot of nice memory properties (sharing the pages mapped, etc..).  Then, the system loads up a (potentially pre optimized and verified) file to load so the vm can start executing it.  You should read [this](http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/dalvik/docs/dexopt.html) document, which will tell you quite a bit about how this works.  (Perhaps [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6925/what-is-the-difference-between-odexed-and-deodexed-roms) thread will also help.)  Keep in mind that as all systems are different -- for example, if you're on a new architecture, you won't get JIT support unless you explicitly write it! -- you can't know *for sure* how Dalvik will load code to run your app.